# read vcf (vcard) labels and values

Tags: php, pear, vcf-vcard

I am trying to read a vcf, I am already getting the values, but unable to retrieve the type and prefixes.
Please see following code

```php
<?php
require_once( 'Contact_Vcard_Parse.php' );
if ( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] )
{
  $parse = new Contact_Vcard_Parse();
  $cardinfo = $parse->fromFile( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] );
  foreach( $cardinfo as $card )
  {
    $first = $card['N'][0]['value'][0][0];
    $last = $card['N'][0]['value'][1][0];
    $email = $card['EMAIL'][0]['value'][0][0];
    $telcount=0;
    while($telcount<50)
    {       
      $teltitle = $card['TEL'][$telcount]['node'][0][0];
      $tel = $card['TEL'][$telcount]['value'][0][0];
      if(strlen($tel)>=10) 
      { 
        echo 'title : '.$teltitle.'&nbsp;&nbsp;TEL : '.$tel.'<br>'; 
      }
      $telcount++; 
    } 
?>
    email : <?php echo( $email ); ?>
    <br>n : <?php echo( $first ); ?> <br>fn : <?php echo( $last ); ?> <br>
<?php 
  } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: @MarlonBuendia https://pear.php.net/package/Contact_Vcard_Parse the library op is using is deprecated. But this resources may help; https://github.com/nuovo/vCard-parser http://sourceforge.net/projects/vcardphp/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971522/parsing-vcard-in-php

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/nuovo/vCard-parser

I was this vCard-parser before an year. Its working like a charm. You can use this library in your code.

PS: Dont reinvent the wheel.. :)

Comment: i think the owner of the question is not active for years haha

Comment: Yeah , 
i had forgotten about this thread.
thanks all for puting your time into it.

Comment: :) Good question robin.. VCF is dying though

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any libraries:

```
$VArquivoApple = fopen("./contactsapple.vcf", 'r');
$VArrayApple = [];
while (($VLinha = fgetcsv($VArquivoApple)) !== false)
    $VArrayApple[] = $VLinha[0];
fclose($VArquivoApple);

$VAContatosApple = [];

for ($Vi = 0; $Vi < count($VArrayApple); $Vi++) {
    if ($VArrayApple[$Vi] == "BEGIN:VCARD")
        $VContatoApple = new stdClass();
    if ($VArrayApple[$Vi] != "BEGIN:VCARD" && $VArrayApple[$Vi] != "VERSION:3.0") {
        if ($VArrayApple[$Vi] != "END:VCARD") {
            $VAtributo = isset(explode(":", $VArrayApple[$Vi])[0]) ? explode(":", $VArrayApple[$Vi])[0] : "";
            $VValor = isset(explode(":", $VArrayApple[$Vi])[1]) ? explode(":", $VArrayApple[$Vi])[1] : "";
            $VContatoApple->{$VAtributo} = $VValor;
        } else
            $VAContatosApple[] = $VContatoApple;
    }
}

foreach ($VAContatosApple as $value) {
    var_dump($value);
}
```