# Parsing vCard in php

Tags: php, vcf-vcard

Hi i want to parse vCard format to a array. User may upload vCard 2,1 or vCard 3.0 i should  be able to parse it. I just want the email with names in the vCard in to a php array.

i have tried vcardphp.sourceforge.net.

```
<?php

require("vcard.php");

$cards = parse_vcards(file('sample.txt'));
print_r($cards);


function parse_vcards($lines)
{
    $cards = array();
    $card = new VCard();
    while ($card->parse($lines)) {
        $property = $card->getProperty('N');
        if (!$property) {
            return "";
        }
        $n = $property->getComponents();
        $tmp = array();
        if ($n[3]) $tmp[] = $n[3];      // Mr.
        if ($n[1]) $tmp[] = $n[1];      // John
        if ($n[2]) $tmp[] = $n[2];      // Quinlan
        if ($n[4]) $tmp[] = $n[4];      // Esq.
        $ret = array();
        if ($n[0]) $ret[] = $n[0];
        $tmp = join(" ", $tmp);
        if ($tmp) $ret[] = $tmp;
        $key = join(", ", $ret);
        $cards[$key] = $card;
        // MDH: Create new VCard to prevent overwriting previous one (PHP5)
        $card = new VCard();
    }
    ksort($cards);
    return $cards;
}
?>
```

Undefined index: ENCODING in H:\www\vcardphp\vcard.php on line 146
Notice: Undefined index: CHARSET in H:\www\vcardphp\vcard.php on line 149

and the sample code given doesnt work at all Too many  Undefined index: errors

Comment: -1 for script request. Show the code you already have and explain what problems you run into, and I just might reconsider.

Comment: You get `Undefined index` notices because the vcard code uses indexes without checking whether or not they exist. You could reduce the error level to hide those messages, but that's not the best idea. Fixing the code so these messages are not triggered is better.

Answer (score 0):

It's just that the http://vcardphp.sourceforge.net/ sample doesn't work with the given code.  You can modify the code to make it work (so it doesn't fail on missing data - first from vbook.php:

See the added:          `if (!empty($n[*])) $tmp[] = $n[*];`

```
function parse_vcards(&$lines)
{
    $cards = array();
    $card = new VCard();
    while ($card->parse($lines)) {
        $property = $card->getProperty('N');
        if (!$property) {
            return "";
        }
        $n = $property->getComponents();
        $tmp = array();
        if (!empty($n[3])) $tmp[] = $n[3];      // Mr.
        if (!empty($n[1])) $tmp[] = $n[1];      // John
        if (!empty($n[2])) $tmp[] = $n[2];      // Quinlan
        if (!empty($n[4])) $tmp[] = $n[4];      // Esq.
        $ret = array();
        if (!empty($n[0])) $ret[] = $n[0];
        $tmp = join(" ", $tmp);
        if ($tmp) $ret[] = $tmp;
        $key = join(", ", $ret);
        $cards[$key] = $card;
        // MDH: Create new VCard to prevent overwriting previous one (PHP5)
        $card = new VCard();
    }
    ksort($cards);
    return $cards;
}
```

And modify the vcard.php parse function to accomodate not having the expected parameters.

```
function parse(&$lines)
{
    while (list(, $line) = each($lines)) {
        $line = rtrim($line);
        $tmp = split_quoted_string(":", $line, 2);
        if (count($tmp) == 2) {
            $this->value = $tmp[1];
            $tmp = strtoupper($tmp[0]);
            $tmp = split_quoted_string(";", $tmp);
            $this->name = $tmp[0];
            $this->params = array();
            for ($i = 1; $i < count($tmp); $i++) {
                $this->_parseParam($tmp[$i]);
            }
            $encoding_defined = array_key_exists('ENCODING', $this->params);
            if ($encoding_defined && $this->params['ENCODING'][0] == 'QUOTED-PRINTABLE') {
                $this->_decodeQuotedPrintable($lines);
            }
            $charset_defined = array_key_exists('CHARSET', $this->params);
            if ($charset_defined && $this->params['CHARSET'][0] == 'UTF-8') {
                $this->value = utf8_decode($this->value);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```